# wp7 facebook integration

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

I want to post a message with a photo using my WP7 app to facebook. I came across wFace while doing some research. Any other recommendations regarding this would be very helpful.

Pratik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with the Facebook Graph API.

Have a look at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo (Scroll down to the section on publishing.)

Comment: Has anyone developed a sample that they could share?